# Unable to extract the date from the datetime string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I am trying to extract only the date from the below timestamp

```
import datetime
date="2021-02-20T00:01:00-05:00"
date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
```

But I am getting below error:

```
ValueError: time data '2021-02-20T00:01:00-05:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Expected:

I need to extract 'only the date' from the above string.

Comment: Have you tried using `-%fZ` instead of `.%fZ`?

Comment: Hi @mkrieger1, i tired but it throw the error similar to above notified

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of `datetime.fromisoformat()` to read the isoformat date

```
import datetime
date="2021-02-20T00:01:00-05:00"

print(datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date).date())
```

output:

```
2021-02-20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

date = "2021-02-20T00:01:00-05:00"
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")

myFormat = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

print("Original", date_time_obj)
print("New", date_time_obj.strftime(myFormat))
```

The issue here is that the time zone is behind, hence the minus. You should not parse this sign.

Comment: HI @cadebe, thanks for the replay. however  i still getting the time along with the date. 
as 2021-02-20 00:01:00, i need only  the date- 2021-02-20

Comment: Then change the format in which you print out the date: myFormat = "%Y-%m-%d"